# Preserving page numbers - adding a page break to the end of every page

Tags: microsoft-word, page-numbers

I'm working with a document where preserving page numbers is very important to ensure consistency across copies - how can I add a page break to the end of the last line of every page, so that when text is edited and margins changed the page numbers are preserved?

Comment: That won't help if your edits or margin changes push text on to the next page ...

Comment: Consider referring to sections/subsections etc. instead of page numbers.